# symfony' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: symfony

I was using official `symfony` documentation on how to install `symfony` and create `symfony` project.
After running the command : `symfony new my_project` I got this error:

```
symfony' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

**What could be the reason of not being able to run this command?**

Comment: symfony executable? I only know composer to setup the project and then app/console for the commands

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just came across this problem and it was driving me crazy until i found the solution. First let me tell you the steps I took:

- My machine is running Windows 7
- went to this site for instructions: http://www.symfony.com/download
- opened up Command Prompt and entered `c:\> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony`
- once it was ready, I ran this command: `php symfony new my_project`
- All failed.
- I kept trying different things even changing PATHs in windows environments but that did nothing
- SOLUTION: I rebooted my machine, then opened up Command Prompt by right clicking on its icon and selecting ***"Run As Administrator"***, followed the steps again, and it finally worked.

In my case, this was the issue. I believe the .phar file was created with errors due to it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

It is confusing how simple instruction given. Here is a simple how-to (assuming you have php command on your windows, Linux is similar or go here http://symfony.com/download):

**Installation on Windows:**

```
c:\> php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"
```

then

```
php symfony new my_new_project 2.8
```

(my_new_project is your project name and 2.8 is the version of symfony) - Done!

**Note:**

So you understand php calls symfony parameter/file to create a symfony project name my_new_project version 2.8 but pay attention that the symfony file is downloaded earlier. So you must have the symfony file in the current directory or use path to point to different location if elsewhere.

Comment: In my case adding php before symfony worked. thanks Dung.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try running:

```
which symfony
```

But I would not expect it to return anything meaningful. Clearly, `symfony` was not registered in `PATH` environment variable right. So, try this:

```
find / -name "symfony"
```

... and copy the path found. Then

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

add the line (before `export PATH....`)

```
export SYMFONY_INSTALL=/path/from/previuous/find/commmand
```

and finally prepend `SYMFONY_INSTALL` to your `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$SYMFONY_INSTALL:.....
```

Save the file and then: `source .bash_profile`

Try running this again: `which symfony`

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Install scoop using following command (https://scoop.sh/)

```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser # Optional: Needed to run a remote script the first time
> irm get.scoop.sh | iex
```

and then install symfony cli

```
scoop install symfony-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is,

1. Download symfony binaries from https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/releases/download/v5.5.6/symfony-cli_windows_amd64.zip
2. Extract the zip files. You will see symfony.exe file.
3. Put the symfony.exe in the project directory.

Solved. Now use Symfony command it will work

Answer (score -1):

First download the symfony binary

```
php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"
```

Then copy the downloaded file into some folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\bin`, so you will reference it later in a command in the `windir` folder containing the needed command, executing

```
echo php "C:\path-to-symfony\symfony" %* > %windir%\symfony.cmd
```

This will work because the `windir` is in the system path and when you execute a command without extension the shell will append automatically append the default ones `exe`, `bat`, `cmd`, at any time you will be able to execute the `symfony` command in the shell, this approach can be reused for others situations as well.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your php.ini file and find the line

extension=php_curl.dll

it will probably be uncommented, comment it! it should look thus

;extension=php_curl.dll

save your file and try to run "php symfony new project_name" again.
it worked for me

Answer (score -3):

the solution is just to :
run CLI as admin
that's all